Can I cache BlobContainerClient?
I am constantly building the full url to a BLOB with the following:
var (containerName, blobName) = SplitFullname(filename);
var container = ServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
var blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);
return blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

The serviceClient I create once at startup and save (this is in a singleton service).
I have 6 containers that my app uses. Can I also cache those 6 BlobContainerClient objects? Or is this something I should create on each use?

There are a few ways. You could use the new .NET 8 DI "keyed services" feature to register several Singleton BlobContainerClient objects - as per this: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-keyed-services-dependency-injection-support/  I can write an answer to demo if you like? However, I'd ask whether it's definitely worth it? Looking at the source code for GetBlobContainerClient it's quite lightweight. I doubt you'll notice enough performance difference to offset the extra effort.

@AndrewB Can you please write an answer saying it's a very lightweight call and therefore just use it? Happy to accept that. TIA


#Can I cache BlobContainerClient?

I agree with Andrew B's comment, the GetBlobContainerClient method is a lightweight call, so you may not notice a significant performance difference by caching the BlobContainerClient objects.
Each time the GetBlobContainerClient method is invoked, it creates a new BlobContainerClient object, which is a simple operation and doesn't involve any network calls.
You can use same code without worrying about caching the BlobContainerClient objects, as it should provide good performance without any significant impact.
Code:
var (containerName, blobName) = SplitFullname(filename);
var container = ServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
var blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(blobName);
return blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

Reference:

BlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(String) Method (Azure.Storage.Blobs) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn
azure blob storage - Should I save BlobServiceClient & BlobContainerClient for the life of my app? - Stack Overflow by Gaurav Mantri.

